# Performance issue with multivalued field in Lucene

Tags: java, performance, indexing, solr, lucene

We're using Lucene 4.7 to build and query a rather large data set (110+ millions documents).

One of the document field, which we used for faceting, is defined as follow:

```
<field name="topic_paths"
       type="string"
       indexed="false"
       stored="false"
       docValues="true"
       multiValued="true"
       termVectors="false"
       termPositions="false"
       termOffsets="false"/>
```

Whenever we include this field in queries, they become extremely slow: about 7 seconds per `topic_path` value included in the search, so about 30 seconds for four `topic_path` values (typical in our case).

Queries that don't use this field are very fast (15 ms).

Is this performance we should expect from Lucene with multi-valued fields used for faceting? Is there anything wrong or suboptimal with our field definition? Are there tricks we could use to speedup searches?

Details:

- Hardware: Xen VM, 8-core Xeon CPU E5-2670 v2 at 2.5 GHz, 64 GB RAM
- OS: Windows Server 2012 Standard
- JVM: started with -Xmx8000m (Lucene is using about 45% of that)
- Lucene queries are single-threaded

Comment: I guess the facets will use docValues so peformance depends on the os filecache efficiency. Do you see a lot IO when you extract facets? If you run the same query a second time is it faster? How much heap space do you give to java (Xmx)?

Comment: If I run the exact same query a second time, it is instant (thanks to the query cache I presume). I don't yet know how much disk traffic queries generate since for some reason I/O counters in Process Explorer are stuck to 0. However queries appear to be CPU-bound. Let me add that individual queries are running single-threaded. We pass `-Xmx8000m` to the JVM; Lucene seems to be using 45% of that.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a matter of warming up the os filecache. Could you try to run a long MatchAllQuery with facets and see if all subsequent facet queries are faster? You can also check the virtual memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

Read this article, http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Fields

You need to "index" you field for including it into search/faceting, otherwise Solr will skipping this field without any exception

Comment: We tried setting `indexed="true"`, however this had no effect on performance. From what I understand, `indexed="true"` is redundant when `docValues="true"` is set.

Comment: We solved our problem by switching to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Elasticsearch will have the same performance issue if you port your setup directly, as they both use Lucene for core search. Your issue is only solved due to changing setups.The index=true is the right answer: Did you re-index everything after you specified that?